# ng-file-upload with dropify not showing thumbnails

Tags: ng-file-upload, dropify

I'm trying to use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and [dropify](https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify) like this:

```
 <input type="file" id="input-file-a" class="dropify"
                 ngf-select ng-model="ctr.picFile" />
```

Uploading is working well, but dropify isn't.

The problem is that dropify is no longer showing any thumbnail previews, any ideas?